# Cannot apply background color to custom navigation using CSS

Tags: html, css

i have no-idea why or how, but i seemingly cannot change the background colour of navbar on my site. I am attempting to create my own WHMCS template inline with my joomla template, and no matter what i do, the background colour will not change?

[The dev site is here](http://www.sitewidedesign.co.uk/hosting)

I want to convert the whole navbar background to black. I can convert the background of the  to black, but the bit to the right of the links stays grey. I'm baffled and figure it must be something stupid that i have done?

This is the HTML i have for my menus:

```
<header id="gkHeader">
     <div>      
        <div class="gkPage" id="gkHeaderNav">
           <a href="https://www.sitewidedesign.co.uk/" id="gkLogo" class="cssLogo">Site Wide Design</a>
           <div id="gkMainMenu">
              <nav id="gkExtraMenu" class="gkMenu">
                 <ul class="gkmenu level0">
                    <li  class="first active"><a href="https://www.sitewidedesign.co.uk/"  class=" first active" id="menu120"  >Home</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="/k2/latest"  id="menu333"  >Blog</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="/faq"  id="menu458"  >FAQ</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="/login/login"  id="menu472"  >Login</a></li>
                    <li  class="last"><a href="/web-hosting"  class=" last" id="menu477"  >Hosting</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </nav>
           </div>
         </div>         
        <div class="gkPreHeader">
            <nav id="gkPreHeaderMenu" class="gkMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li  class="first active"><a href="/hosting/domainchecker.php"  class=" first active" id="menu300"  >Domains</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="hosting/domainchecker.php"  id="menu333"  >Blog</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="/hosting/knowledgebase.php"  id="menu458"  >Knowledgebase</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="/login/login"  id="menu472"  >Login</a></li>
                    <li  class="last"><a href="/hosting/clientarea.php"  class=" last"  >My Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>             
    </div>
```

The one i want to have a black background is the gkPreHeader. I have tried the following css but it does not affect the whole div as you can see on my site.

```
.gkPreHeader {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#000;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome.
Regards
Donna

Comment: I see it fine in your website, without `float` in the header the header size is 100% black background

Comment: At present it's fine. **You should probably remove the question**. When floated the element was collapsing to it's natural width thus you could see the grey background of the `header` to the right of it.

Comment: Ah, I have to agree with OP, it's white for me, refreshed the crap out of that site, still white.. re-sized the window + refresh, still **white** header background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clearfix the nav so it has height.
You can do this (also you can apply this to your first/top menu - .gkMenu):

```
.gkMenu2:before, .gkMenu2:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.gkMenu2::after {
    clear: both;
}
```

After this, the nav is going to have it's height back and you can change the background to it.

A lite reading about the topic: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/